# Nginx Wordpress rewrite for multiple sub-folders

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wordpress

I am currently setting up our new server for our company, and we are developing alot of different apps, and right now we want to have all our wordpress apps under wp.domain.com/app1, wp.domain.com/app2, etc.

The reason the default isn't working is because we want to use the %postname% permalink for all apps.

I am currently managing by doing a rewrite for every single sub-folder, but I'd rather rewrite every single subfolder with one `location` block, so I don't have to edit the server block each time we upload a new application to our server.

There is also a possibility we upload to a sub-sub-directory, for example wp.domain.com/appgroup1/app3, wp.domain.com/appgroup1/app6, etc.

Here's my wp.domain.com config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html/wp;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name wp.domain.com;

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ /(.*)/ {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php?$args;
  }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  #
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
  }

  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # concurs with nginx's one

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Note that we don't have use a multi-site setup.

Comment: Post your complete nginx configuration in the question please.

Comment: Done, see edit.

Comment: This is going to be _really_ messy. You should save yourself a lot of trouble, and just use subdomains.

Comment: So it isn't possible to apply an equivalent of Apache's rewrite on every sub-folder there is? I can live with us not putting them into "sub-sub-folders", but it must be possible to add a simple rewrite for `%postname%` permalinks in each top-level sub-directory, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is time to use regex location blocks :

```
location ~ /(app1|app2|app3|groupapp1(?:/(subapp1|subapp2|subapp3)))/ { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php$is_args$args;
    [ ... ]
}
```

Comment: This would still require me to edit the server block each time I add a app to our site and then restart nginx.

Comment: Then adapt the regex and capture everything if it's what you want using `(.*)`. But it's likely to cause issues.

Comment: Tried with `location ~ /(.*)/ { try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php; index index.php; }` but this downloads the index.php file for some reason.

Comment: @Svenskunganka Do you have a location block handling php files ?

Comment: Yes, the `location /app/ { }` works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Svenskunganka This is not what I asked. You must have a location block forwarding php processing to something. Nginx doesn't process php himself. Post the configuration of this. Check your logs in debug mode too.

Comment: I do have a location block for passing PHP scripts to the FastCGI server. `location ~ \.php$ { lots of stuff here }`. This block works as if I go to a test.php file and echo "test" I get "test" on the page.

Comment: Any more clues?...

Comment: @Svenskunganka The regex `/(.*)/` should be `^/(.*)/*$`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you can just left index index.php throughout the whole server {} block and remove any /app/ locations. You don't need to rewrite anything to index.php.

Comment: The thing I want is Wordpress's %postname% permalink on all the sites under wp.domain.com